# Where has he got the diamond?

Tags: grammaticality, verbs

The sentence, "**Where has he got the diamond?**" was written as a translation to a Russian sentence: "**Откуда у него взялся алмаз?**"

I think it's wrong. The Russian sentence means that the speaker is curious of how come the other person has a diamond (posseses one).

I'd say it is closer to, "**How come does he have a diamond?**"

I was thinking of changing the original to, "**Where did he get the diamond?**" but it sounds like the speaker is curious of **where the person got it** rather than **how come he has it**.

Also, can **gotten** in the original sentence give that meaning?

Comment: To keep this from being a Russian translation question, and to get a better idea of the meaning you intend, could you write a short scenario around the action you are asking about? The intent of the parties involved might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Russian is weak, but I supposed that the Откуда ("From where") made it a question about the source of the diamond, hence "Where did he get the diamond?"

But if you're right about the sense being rather "Why?" or "How does it happen?" then, "Why does he have the diamond?", or more colloquially "How come he has the diamond?"

Note that "How come" is an idiom that can't be analysed in current English, and it is followed by an affirmative not an interrogative word order: "How come he has", not "How come does he have".

Your first try,  "Where has he got the diamond?" could work in context, but out of context I did not understand it until I read your explanation, because for me (British English speaker) "has he got" first means "does he have" rather than "has he obtained"; so the "where" did not at first reading have the force of "where from". But if he has just arrived with the diamond, so we all know where he has it now, then that question could work.

"Gotten" (which I would not use, as I speak BrEng) would indeed help to make the first sentence clearer.

Comment: "**Where did he get the diamond?**" is very close to this, however, it's really hard to explain the Russian meaning. Thanks for the answer. The Russian phrase means both "**How come**" and "**Where**" with curiocity involved.

Comment: @SovereignSun Do you mean something like saying "How could you afford a diamond? You have a low-paying job, after all."

Comment: @user3169 Probably something like this. I guess there should be some slang for **how come and where from did he get the diamond**.

Comment: Two idioms I can think of are: 1) using an intensifier like "on earth" or "the hell": "How the hell did _he_ get a diamond?" and 2) "How did he come by a diamond?" "Come by" implies that his acquisition is surprising or unusual, and possibly shady.